# Merge from upstream with no upstream history

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have a parent repo containing my project, and a sub repo which is based off this project.

The parent repo has tagged releases, and the sub repo is based off one of these tags. For example:

```
parent v1.0---v2.0---v3.0
                \
                 child---[changes]
```

Unfortunately when the child repo was created, the parent history was removed and the repo was reinitialised with the files added from scratch. So this means none of the parent repo's history is contained within the child repo, but rather, one commit at the start to indicate it was based off parent's v2.0 tag where all of the v2.0 files were `git add`ed.

Is there any way to use Git to merge upstream changes from the parent (eg. v3.0 tag) back into child despite there being no parent history?

`git pull` tells me there is no common commits, so it doesn't know where to start merging I guess. Do I need to rewrite the history of the child to add the parent's history back?

Obviously this is a weird scenario and not one I will allow in future :)

Comment: Can you show the git pull output? I tried pulling from a remote branch with no common commits and it merges fine..

Comment: @JonasBerlin I think you are right actually - apologies as I actually tried doing a patch on changes between v2.0 and v3.0 which failed. Thanks for getting me to try the git pull (and sorry for not writing the question correctly originally - I just assumed the pull would fail like the patch did)

Comment: @JonasBerlin actually this doesn't do exactly what I wanted, and wouldn't really work for upgrades - due to the lack of history every changed file appears as a merge conflict. New files added are fine, but obviously Git should be able to resolve merges if it has the history to do so. Thanks, but I think my question is still valid

Answer (score 0):

Then I suggest you rewrite the history of the child repo to have the full history from v2.0 backwards.

I assume the branch is called `master` in both repos.

So first we add a remote for the parent repo and fetch it

```
$ cd /path/to/child/repo
$ git remote add origin <url_or_path_for_parent_repo>
$ git fetch origin
```

Then you find out the sha of the `v2.0` tag (the one with the full history):

```
$ git rev-parse v2.0
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

and the sha of the first commit in the `master` branch, i.e. the one with the entire v2.0 history squashed into one commit:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git log --reverse --format=format:%H | head -n 1
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Then, we rewrite the `master` branch to swap the parent bbbbb.. to aaaaa... (please replace bbbbb... and aaaaa... strings in the command below with the actual results of commands run above)

```
$ git filter-branch --parent-filter 'read p ; if [ "$p" = "-p bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" ]; then echo "-p aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" ; else echo "$p" ; fi'
Rewrite cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc (d/d)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
```

After this your `master` branch should now have replaced the first squashed commit with the history of the `v2.0` tag.

If something went wrong, you can revert the `master` branch back to the original state with:

```
$ git reset --hard original/refs/heads/master
```

After you have verified the results and are happy, you can get rid of the `original/refs/heads/master` backup branch by:

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

After this you will be able to just merge the `v3.0` tag into the `master` branch of your child repo in a normal fashion.